# Multi-armed Bandit :a lower bound for the expected sample size from an inferior population

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, multiarmed-bandit

I am reading [Asymptotically efficient adaptive allocation rules](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196885885900028) to study the multi-armed bandit problem, and have a question.

The question is about the proof of Theorem 2.

> THEOREM 2. Assume that $I(\theta, \lambda)$ satisfies (1.6) and (1.7) and that $\Theta$ satisfies (1.9). Fix $j\in \{1, \dots, k\}$, and define $\Theta_j$ and $\Theta_j^*$ by (2.1). Let $\varphi$ be any rule such that for every $\theta \in \Theta_j^*$, as $n\to \infty$
>   $$\sum_{i\neq j}E_\theta T_n(i) = o(n^a)$$
>   where $T_n(i)$, defined in (1.2), is the number of times that the rule $\varphi$ samples from $\Pi_i$ up to stage $n$. Then for every $\theta \in \Theta_j$ and every $\epsilon > 0$,
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P_\theta\{T_n(j) \geq (1-\epsilon)(\log{n})/I(\theta_j, \theta^*)\}=1,$$
>   where $\theta^*$ is defined in (1.4), and hence
>   $$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}E_\theta T_n(j)/\log{n}\geq 1/I(\theta_j, \theta^*).$$

The proof starts as follows:

> Proof. To fix the ideas let $j=1$, $\theta \in \Theta_1$, and $\theta^*=\theta_2$. Then $\mu(\theta_2)>\mu(\theta_1)$ and $\mu(\theta_2)\geq \mu(\theta_1)$ for $3\leq i\leq k$. Fix any $0<\delta <1$. In view of (1.6), (1.7), and (1.9), we can choose $\lambda \in \Theta$ such that
>   $$\mu(\lambda)>\mu(\theta_2) \text{ and } |I(\theta_1, \lambda)-I(\theta_1, \theta_2)|<\delta I(\theta_1, \theta_2).$$
>   Define the new parameter vector $\gamma=(\lambda, \theta_2, \dots, \theta_k)$. Then $\gamma\in\Theta_1^*$, so by (2.2)
>   $$E_\gamma(n-T_n(1))=\sum_{h\neq 1}E_\gamma(T_n(h))=o(n^a)$$
>   with $0<a<\delta$, and therefore
>   $$(n-O(\log{n}))P_\gamma\{T_n(1)<(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda)\}\leq E_\gamma(n-T_n(1))=o(n^a)$$
>   ...

What I do not understand is the last inequality. How is this derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a restriction of the integral domain:

\begin{align}
E_\gamma(n-T_n(1)) &= \int_\Omega (n-T_n(1))\\
                   &\geq \int_{\{T_n(1)<(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda)\}}(n-T_n(1))\\
                   &\geq \int_{\{T_n(1)<(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda)\}}(n-(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda))\\
                   &\geq (n-(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda))P_\gamma\{T_n(1)<(1-\delta)(\log{n})/I(\theta_1, \lambda)\}
\end{align}